# How do I use Drupal to call my CSS or JavaScript files in another page and include them in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, regex, drupal, gmail

Hi I'm a novice Drupal developer and was hoping someone can help give me advice on how to include standalone JS and CSS files in my webpages. I currently have 1 file for each page and I place the CSS and js validation on that one PHP file. I want to be able to include them both from separate files on multiple web pages.

Thanks!

Comment: whats gmail and regex got to do with your question?

Comment: because once I know how to include files, I can implement an email server and use regex. Are you offering any help at all or just pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The process for adding CSS & JavaScipt to Drupal pages has changed from D7 to D8. In Drupal 8, you first need to declare a library for the additions using a *.libraries.yml file. See the tutorials below for more information:

- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)
- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)